I want to get the cost according to room-id which is define in form and i want to get using $('cost').keyup this how can i achieve
I am unable to calculate using class? I am trying to access dynamic id using class
@foreach($room_types as $room_type)

 {!! Form::text('cost', null, ['class' => 'form-control cost-'.$room_type->id, 'placeholder' => 'Enter Cost']) !!}
 {!! $errors->first('cost','<span class="help-block text-danger">:message</span>') !!}   
@endforeach

and this is the script
$('.cost{{ $room_type->id }}').keyup(function() {

      var roomTypeId = $(this).data('room-type-id');
                    
      var cost           = parseFloat($('.cost').val());
      var profit         = parseFloat($('.profit').val());
      var tax_percentage = parseFloat($('.tax-percentage').val());

      checkNum('.cost'); 
      total_cost    = calculate_total_cost(cost, profit, tax_percentage);
      $('.total-cost').val(total_cost);

});


cost-...id vs cost..id?

how can do this could you give me some code snippets

I mean you may refer to the wrong class name.
Correct one (suppose the blade one is correct) should be $('.cost-{{ $room_type->id }}'), but you used $('.cost{{ $room_type->id }}') in you jquery part.

yes right i had missed that now working thanks
